# SVG load to Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to make a svg widget load inside my Krita docker to act as a cursor. Krita is a painting program and it uses python and PyQt5 to load up plugins. I made a blank docker with the bare minimum for it to load. If anything is add will be in the Area marked with "Testing".

However my SVG load method seems not to be working when compared with other references, and i think it might be the path to the frame itself as I try to place the viewer that I loaded.

```
# Import Krita
from krita import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui, QtSvg, uic
import os.path

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtSvg

# Set Window Title Name
DOCKER_NAME = "Blank"

# Create Docker
class BlankDocker(DockWidget):
    """
    Comments
    """
    # Initialize the Dicker Window
    def __init__(self):
        super(BlankDocker, self).__init__()

        # Window Title
        self.setWindowTitle(DOCKER_NAME)
        # Widget
        self.window = QWidget()
        self.layout = uic.loadUi(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/blank.ui', self.window)
        self.setWidget(self.window)

        # TESTING###################################################################################

        self.viewer = QtSvg.QSvgWidget()
        self.viewer.load('C:/Users/EyeOd/AppData/Roaming/krita/pykrita/blank/Notes/cursor_lmb.svg')
        self.viewer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0,0,200,200))

        self.layout.frame.addWidget(self.viewer) #??

        ############################################################################################
    # Change the Canvas
    def canvasChanged(self, canvas):
        pass
```

The area of interest of the *.UI file I load is the QFrame = "frame" in which I want to place the widget inside to move around inside.
http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=b7083dbb5e13adafcddb9ee9fdfa8fcd

Comment: If `self.layout.frame` is a reference to a QFrame, `addWidget` won't do nothing (except from giving back an exception). Try to set a layout for that frame (just add any widget to the frame in Designer, so that you can set a layout for the frame, then remove that widget), and then use `self.layout.frame.layout().addWidget(self.viewer)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QFrame doesn't have any method called addWidget so you should have an exception. So if you want to place the QSvgWidget in the QFrame you have 2 alternatives:

- Set as parent of QSvgWidget to QFrame.

  ```
  self.viewer = QtSvg.QSvgWidget(self.window.frame)
  self.viewer.load('C:/Users/EyeOd/AppData/Roaming/krita/pykrita/blank/Notes/cursor_lmb.svg')
  self.viewer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 200, 200))
  ```
- Use a layout:

  ```
  self.viewer = QtSvg.QSvgWidget()
  self.viewer.load('C:/Users/EyeOd/AppData/Roaming/krita/pykrita/blank/Notes/cursor_lmb.svg')
  lay = QVBoxLayout(self.window.frame)
  lay.addWidget(self.viewer)
  ```

---

<sub>**Note**: If you use `self.layout = uic.loadUi(..., self.window)` then you will see that self.layout is the same self.window object so to avoid confusion it is advisable to use `uic.loadUi(..., self.window)`</sub>